# VS2010 crashes with .NET Micro framework projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-micro-framework

I just installed .net micro framework SDK, but when I make a new project and run it ( even without any code of my own ), VS crashes.

[image]

Comment: Try starting it with `devenv /safemode`.

Comment: hmm... how do i do that?

Comment: "Start" -> "All Programs" -> "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010" -> "Visual Studio Tools" -> "Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)". Then type "`devenv /safemode`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that anything would be released in that state, so it's likely to be a misconfiguration or glitch on your PC - a reinstall of both VS and the framework might fix it. (I also would recommend a full install of VS rather than cutting out components you don't think you will need, as this always seems to lead to increased problems)

If you have another development PC available, you could try installing it on that to see if it's repeatable, which would be a quick guide as to whether it's just your PC or something more chronic.

If you can repeat it, then try Help > Report a Bug and report it to Microsoft - they usually respond quickly to bug reports, may be able to suggest a workaround, and certainly take bugs seriously - several crashes and niggles I had were fixed for SP1, which may not have been noticed if I hadn't reported them.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue its fixed now. I downloaded the [4.1SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8515) and installed it, everything is smooth.